# Lua - how to delete more then 1 from the result

Tags: lua, roblox

I have here some Game code. Its to auto delete what I get. But I get always 3 but the Script only delete one. How I could change it? Thanks!

```
local DeletePet = function(PetID)
game["Workspace"]["__REMOTES"]["Game"]["Inventory"]:InvokeServer("Delete",  PetID)
end
```

Comment: U have to share a bit more code, for instance of `InvokeServer`.

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/v3Bux62y)

Comment: @jeromesuckrow Welcome to SO. Your question is a little tricky for the SO format at this point. The code and explanation you put into your question is too little to understand your problem, but the link you provided is way too much, not many people will read that (additionally code should never be provided by link, only by putting it in the question). Can you try to build a minimal example that illustrates your problem? Alternatively, add all party of your code that are directly involved in your problem to your question using the edit button.

Answer (score 1):

Jerome, could you please post where you're setting up the **OnServerInvoke** event? I don't see it in the code you're referencing to Csaar. I'm also afraid I don't quite understand what you're meaning when you ask `how to delete more then 1 from the result`. If you could clarify a bit further upon this, then I might be able to further assist you.

Also, please keep in mind that Roblox code is rather niche and you'll have a higher chance of getting answers in a Roblox oriented environment like the recommended [Scripting Helpers](https://scriptinghelpers.org/) forum. That's not to say the people here aren't very skilled, but they may not be accustomed to the Roblox API.

Comment: This should be in the comment section

Comment: I can't comment. Thanks though.